# Create view or select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im new with SQL and have some issue to generate view. This is my current table structure :

| Place | Person | Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MarketA | PersonA | Apple |
| MarketB | PersonA | Orange |
| MarketB | PersonA | Apple |
| MarketC | PersonB | Orange |
| MarketA | PersonC | Apple |
| MarketB | PersonD |  |

My goal is to create view like below :

| Person | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| PersonA | Apple/Orange |
| PersonB | Orange |
| PersonC | Apple |
| PersonD |  |

Can help me on how can i achieve this?

Comment: Where are you stuck, exactly? You need to explain where your difficulty is.

Comment: When people start doing the job for everyone who asks a question without the details that Larnu (in this case) was asking about, the general quality of SO will go down (even further).

Comment: @Larnu I'm just not have idea how can i archive this.. either it's possible or not at SQL layer.

Comment: @Luuk Sure i will post any error if im facing any difficulties, but here I dont have any idea where i can start or keyword that I can google to check the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it will help if you add a CREATE TABLE to your question, but your table example also really helps.
You can achieve this (especially in earlier versions of SQL Server) with this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person,
        STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT '/' + A.Fruit Fruits
                    FROM TableA  A
                    WHERE A.Person = B.Person
                    ORDER BY Fruits
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
                1,
                1,
                ''
            ) Fruit
FROM TableA B
```

I know in SQL 2017/2019 there is an easier way, but call me old fashioned...

Comment: That's going to return XML, not a dataset.

Comment: Answered too quickly, I corrected the code.

Comment: Thanks @RonaldHensbergen . this is what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
WITH groupedtable AS (
SELECT DISTINCT Person, Fruit
FROM yourtable
)
SELECT Person, STRING_AGG(Fruit, '/') AS Fruit
FROM groupedtable
GROUP BY Person;
```

See **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=032da7e81f4badb06c2571066f4c225d)**

Comment: Sorry not mention about my SQL version.. it's not support STRING_AGG. But thanks for the demo, looks work fine if supported and really helpfull for me to explore.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? And what version?

Comment: Hey @Okechukwu Ossai, Im using SQL server 2016 which STRING_AGG not supported

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL SERVER 2017 or above:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT PERSON, STRING_AGG(Fruit,'/') AS Fruit
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT PERSON, Fruit
   FROM  groupedtable
)a
GROUP BY Person;
```

Comment: `STRING_AGG` was added in 2017, not 2016. Also, this won't give the right result for PersonA

Comment: Not tested but forgive me not mentioning my SQL server not support STRING_AGG ..